# How can I access my BIOS settings now?

Tags: bios

I cannot access my Thinkpad E430c BIOS setting even I press any of my keys after installing UBUNTU 14.04 32bit. 
HELP !!!

Comment: Installing Ubintu can not change anything about way you acces the BIOS settings. Make sure you press the right keys, and press them early enough - sounds like you may press the right keys, but too late.

Comment: The question looks like being off topic - but as it is asked under the assumption it is Ubuntu related, and Ubuntu may at least contribute to the way the problem appears to the OP, I'm not sure it should be closed as off topic.

Comment: According to [BIOS Setup Utility Access Keys for Popular Computer Systems](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_pc.htm) *ThinkPad: Press F1 or F2 after powering on the computer*. [Other reference](http://superuser.com/questions/679111/opening-bios-menu/679124#679124) *I tried it before and it didn't work, but the F1 works if I spam it [press the key repeatedly] very quickly seconds after the computer turns on.*

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu can not change anything about the way you acces the BIOS settings.

But I can imagine that the timing of the visual steps of the boot process change a lot, which could be confusing regarding the time of when to press the key to access the BIOS settings.

Make sure you press the right keys, and press them early enough - it sounds like you may press the right keys, but too late.

As @karel found, it should be F1 or F2 after powering up. He points out that he needed to press F1 in quick succession on startup to see the BIO settings.
Note that this is independant of installing Ubuntu - the handling of that key happens before Ubuntu is touched on the harddisk.